# Error "undefined" al querer mostrar el resultado de .find almacenado en una variable en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, undefined, find

Acá utilizo el método .find para verificar si la película se encuentra en el Array de objetos y de esta manera no duplicar entradas, pero al querer mostrar la variable "resultado" donde almaceno lo que .find encuentra, salta el error de "undefined" que aparece por consola.

```
let nombrePelicula
let anioPelicula
let duracionPelicula
let generoPelicula
let directorPelicula
let actorPrincipal
let actorSecundario

function ingresarPelicula() {

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese Nombre de la Película: "
    nombrePelicula = verificarTexto(pedirTexto)

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese el año de estreno:  "
    anioPelicula = verificarNumero(pedirTexto)

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese la duración:  "
    duracionPelicula = verificarNumero(pedirTexto)

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese el género: "
    generoPelicula = verificarTexto(pedirTexto) // En entregas próximas se pondrá un selector de Generos

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese el Director: "
    directorPelicula = verificarTexto(pedirTexto)

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese el Actor/Actriz Principal: "
    actorPrincipal = verificarTexto(pedirTexto)

    pedirTexto = "Ingrese el Actor/Actriz Secundaria: "
    actorSecundario = verificarTexto(pedirTexto)
}

function verificarTexto(pedirTexto) {
    let textoaIngresar = pedirTexto
    verificador = 0;
    do {
        textoIngresado = prompt(textoaIngresar);
        if (textoIngresado != "") {
            textoIngresado = textoIngresado.toUpperCase();
            verificador = 1;
            return textoIngresado;
        }
    } while (verificador == 0);
}

function verificarNumero(pedirTexto) {
    let textoaIngresar = pedirTexto
    verificador = 0;
    do {
        numeroIngresado = Number(prompt(textoaIngresar));
        if (numeroIngresado > 0) {
            verificador = 1;
            return numeroIngresado;
        }
    } while (verificador == 0);
}

class Pelicula {
    constructor(nombre, anio, duracion, genero, director, principal, secundario) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.duracion = duracion;
        this.genero = genero;
        this.director = director;
        this.principal = principal;
        this.secundario = secundario;
    }
    mostrar() {
        this.Tarjeta = "La Película " + nombrePelicula + " se estrenó en el Año " + anioPelicula + "\n su duración es de " + duracionPelicula + " minutos \n Es una Película de " + generoPelicula + " la misma fué Dirigida por " + directorPelicula + "\n y su Actor/Actriz Principal es " + actorPrincipal + "\n y su Actor/Actriz Secundario/a es " + actorSecundario;
    }
}

const peliculas = [];
peliculas.push(new Pelicula("Avatar", 2009, 162, "Ciencia Ficción", "James Cameron", "Sam Worthington", "Sigourney Weaver"));
peliculas.push(new Pelicula("The Ring", 2002, 116, "Terror", "Gore Verbinski", "Naomi Watts", "Martin Henderson"));
peliculas.push(new Pelicula("Fun with Dick & Jane", 2005, 91, "Comedia", "Dean Parisot", "Jim Carrey", "Téa Leoni"));
peliculas.push(new Pelicula("The Terminator", 1984, 108, "Acción", "James Cameron", "Arnold Schwarzenegger", "Linda Hamilton"));

let deseaContinuar = "";
do {
    ingresarPelicula();
    const peliculaIngresada = new Pelicula(nombrePelicula, anioPelicula, duracionPelicula, generoPelicula, directorPelicula, actorPrincipal, actorSecundario);
 
    const resultado = peliculas.find(verificarPelicula => verificarPelicula.nombre === nombrePelicula && verificarPelicula.anio === anioPelicula);
    console.log(resultado);
    if (resultado == undefined){
        peliculas.push(peliculaIngresada);
    } else {
        alert("La Pelicula ya se encuentra cargada en la Base")
    }

    deseaContinuar = prompt("Desea Ingresar otra Película? (S/N)");
    deseaContinuar = deseaContinuar.toUpperCase();

} while (deseaContinuar != "N");

for(const peliculaIngresada of peliculas) {
    document.write("<ul>");
    document.write("<li>Pelicula: " + peliculaIngresada.nombre + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Año: " + peliculaIngresada.anio + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Duración: " + peliculaIngresada.duracion + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Genero: " + peliculaIngresada.genero + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Dirección: " + peliculaIngresada.director + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Actor/Actriz Principal: " + peliculaIngresada.principal + "</li>");
    document.write("<li>Actor/Actriz Secundaria: " + peliculaIngresada.secundario + "</li>");
    document.write("</ul>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el `find` estás comparando los nombres de las películas sin tener en cuenta las mayúsculas. Si imprimes por consola el array de películas y `nombrePelicula` verás que este último está en mayúsculas mientras que `verificarPelicula.nombre` no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El `undefined` que recibes del `console.log(resultado)` no es un error, es el valor esperado de un [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#valor_devuelto) que no logra encontrar una coincidencia.

Con la función `verificarTexto()` estás transformando todo el input a mayúsculas, pero el nombre de tus películas existentes sólo tiene en mayúsculas la primera letra, por esa razón resultado es undefined.

Si el texto ingresado siempre será guardado en mayúsculas, puedes hacer lo mismo con el nombre de la película que estás comparando para que la igualdad se cumpla.

```
const resultado = peliculas.find(verificarPelicula => verificarPelicula.nombre.toUpperCase() === nombrePelicula && verificarPelicula.anio === anioPelicula);
```

De todos modos recibirás undefined cuando la película no exista, pero no es necesario que indiques explícitamente undefined en el if dentro del do while.

```
/* Si resultado contiene un valor (que no es undefined), 
ya existe la película y muestra la alerta, 
caso contrario añade una nueva película */

if(resultado) {
    alert("La Pelicula ya se encuentra cargada en la Base")
} else {
    peliculas.push(peliculaIngresada);
}
```